# TortoiseSVN working copy switching from one machine to another machine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a TortoiseSVN working copy in my PC. How can the same working copy can be moved to new PC without SVN check out option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working copy can be moved in any fashion (network drive, USB drive, zipped, etc.) as long as the hidden folders that contain the svn information (named .svn if I recall correctly) are copied along with the source code.

If the path from the new PC to the svn repository is different than it was on the old pc, you may need to use the svn *switch* functionality before you commit so that TortoiseSVN can locate the repository.